# Is there a way to set <nuxt-link> dynamic path?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm trying to pass a button component with `<nuxt-link>` into a parent component which I'm than reusing several times across the app. I'm trying to figure out, how to set the `<nuxt-link>` dynamically so that I can change the path when I'm reusing the parent component again.

I tried something like this:

```
<nuxt-link :to="'/' + path">
     <div class="button">
        <p>{{buttonTitle}}</p>
     </div>
</nuxt-link>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'primaryButton',
    props: ['buttonTitle'],
  }
</script>
```

But this is obviously wrong. Is there a way to use props maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think this would be wrong? It's a perfectly valid usage and anything can be the result of a JS expression in a Vue template. I guess that `<nuxt-link>` is placed in a `<template>`, right? Not having a `<template>` wrapper is a game stopper in Vue SFC's, with the exception of functional components.

Comment: I think this approach might work, but how do I define the page/path or component which I want the button to go to? I need to somehow pass the  attribute "path"  into the component and I'm not sure how

Comment: Define a "path" prop on the component, either required or having a default value. You will then use it as `<primary-button />` <= uses default path or `<primary-button path="your-path-here" />`.